# Seeking weather data for past and this year for 4500 cities around world

Tags: data-request, weather, data

I'm looking for weather data on 4500 cities throughout the world for 2022 and 2023 for a school project.

Is there a way to get this for free?

I can see it according to weather stations, but that might be too much to compile.

Is there anything city level directly available?

I tried APIs but they allow very limited use for free

Comment: Tell us what you tried. Post the URLs. [Show us](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) any code you've written so far. Obtaining recent historic weather data for 4500 US airports + cities should not be difficult, given the number of public and private data sources that offer .CSVs and API access. If you can solve the problem for a small part of the world, such as the U.S., that should put you on firmer footing to merge in data from organizations in other parts of the world.

Comment: I found an API which offers 1 million free calls. Thanks

Comment: The site docs [describe](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) how you should post that API's URL.